# LibX11 Exception on C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, opentk

I want to create a program in C# that uses OpenTK. I download the nuget package with this:

```
nuget.exe install OpenTK
```

and also

```
nuget.exe install OpenTK.GLControl
```

But whenever I reference these 2 files, the console ends up printing this error:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in OpenTK.dll
Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'libX11': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

And upon further investigation, libX11 is a Linux package but I'm running on Windows 10. Is there a way to bypass the Linux check and be able to use it on Windows?

There is no code with it because I can't even properly reference the file without it printing that exception.

I have attempted to put this into System32 and all to no avail.

Comment: Clearly this is only meant for Mono running on Linux.

Comment: Is there any possible Windows build that can be referenced?

Comment: I am also experiencing this error. The interesting thing is that while I get the error on my computer, the project it is occurring in works fine on other Windows machines (as in, an identical binary copy of the project and the relevant opentk libraries). I have also not been able to reproduce the error with a test project. My speculation is that opentk is improperly detecting the platform based on some other libraries that have been loaded, but this is honestly a wild stab in the dark.